# server error access SharePoint vm

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, 2016

Have anyone tried to connect Sharepoint url to access sp vm hosted on azure through C# CSOM

```
using (ClientContext ctx= new ClientContext(siteurl))
{
............
.
.
.
.
.
..
.
.
.

ctx.Load(web);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

this code doesn't work, getting

> "Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **NOT Supported**.

To connect to a SharePoint site hosted in Azure SharePoint Virtual Machine, you should use [SharePoint REST endpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973) instead of using CSOM.